# How to use an XML File to store information VB

Tags: xml, vb.net

can someone show me an example of how to compare user input to the contents of the following XML File? I've been looking for a while but I cant find any examples that I understand properly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Users>
    <User>
        <id>1</id>
        <firstName>Garry</firstName>
        <userName>Domain\Garry</userName>
        <hashedkey>Example1</hashedkey>
    </User>
    <User>
        <id>2</id>
        <firstName>Ben</firstName>
        <userName>Domain\ben</userName>
        <hashedkey>Example2</hashedkey>
    </User>
</Users>
```

An example of what I want to do is:

```
If txtFirstName.text = XML.FirstName AND txtHashedkey.text = XML.hashedkey then 
msgbox("Key matches"
else
msgbox("Key doesnt match"
end if
```

I obviously need to make sure the key matches for that particular user and not have the key in `<id>1</id>` match the key in `<id>2</id>` whilst the name is under `<id>1</id>`. Could someone please give me an example on how to do this?

Comment: This is not a tutorial site: your question would be better received if you posted what you tried and posed a specific question.  That said,  XML may be the wrong way to save that data - anyone could edit the file to replace the hash with something else.

Comment: Hi Plutonix, I am encrypting the XML file, I didn't mention that to avoid the complexity.

Comment: So you have two issues: encrypting and decrypting a text file, and saving and parsing XML. Still not a tutorial site. If you have tried something and have run into a specific problem, this site will be more helpful to you.

Comment: I understand that my original post lacked any source code, i'll update it in a few minutes. But I do not have an issue with the encryption/decryption side of it, I have code which works fine there. I simply am not used to working with XML. My appologise for the lack-luster post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [LINQ to Xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384460.aspx)

```
Dim givenFirstName As String = txtFirstName.Text
Dim givenHashedKey As String = txtHashedkey.Text

Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(pathToFile)
Dim result As XElement = 
    doc.Root.
        Elements("User").
        FirstOrDefault(Function(user)
                           return user.Element("firstName").Value.Equals(givenFirstName) AndAlso
                                  user.Element("hashedkey").Value.Equals(givenHashedKey)
                       End Function)
```

Where `doc.Root` is a root node ("Users").
`Elements("User")` return collection of all "User" xml nodes.
`FirstOrDefault(lambda...)` will execute our "check" expression and return first element where both `firstName` and `hashedkey` are equals to given values.

Edit:
If you need count of matching elements then use `Count` method with same predicate. Below example which use vb.net only feature [Xml Axis Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384769.aspx)

```
Dim amountOfElements As Integer = 
    doc.Root.<User>.Count(Function(user)
                              return user.<firstName>.Value.Equals(givenFirstName) AndAlso
                                     user.<hashedkey>.Value.Equals(givenHashedKey)
                          End Function)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It appears to work but I don't know how to put it into an If statement to check the returned value amount.

Comment: with XML Literals `Dim matches = doc.<Users>.<User>.Any(Function(u) u.<firstName>.Value = "Ben" AndAlso u.<hashedkey>.Value = "Example2")`. A small problem if there are a lot of users is that the whole XML file is loaded into memory, but that seems nothing compared to encrypting and decrypting the file each time.

Comment: My usercase isn't going to have more than ~10 users, so I wouldn't expect too many issues.

Comment: @Slai, you right, but it is not `Xml Literals`, it is `Xml Axis properties` :)